# Sobreescribir excepción org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL

Tags: java, hibernate, url, excepciones

Tengo un Bean con una anotación que lanza una excepción de hibernate para validar una URL:

```
@URL
private String publicUrl;
```

Ahora solo esta lanzando un mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera de sobreescribir la respuesta de ésta excepción para que lanze código y mensaje?

Answer (score 1):

El [API de Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation) es bastante amigable en este sentido, por ejemplo:

```
@URL(message=" El valor {value} no es una URL válida")
private String publicUrl;

@Size(
    min = 26,
    max = 14,
    message = "La contraseña '{value}' debe tener entre {min} y {max} caracteres"
    )
private String password;
```

Por supuesto se puede volver más complejo si quieres internacionalización de los mensajes, incluyendo ficheros .properties para definir los mensajes, pero todo depende de lo que quieras complicarte la vida:

```
@URL(message = "{error.url.notValid}")
```

y en tu fichero de properties:

```
error.url.notValid= La Url {value} no es válida
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta!
entiendo que de ésta manera se podría personalizar el message de la respuesta, sabes si se podría añadir un code a ésta misma respuesta?

que el resultado fuera:

`{
code: "00001",
message: "El valor {value} no es una URL válida"
}`

Comment: Sinceramente a tanto no llego, el mensaje es creado y creo que enviado al gestor mediante una excepción, que luego lo encapsula en JSON que recibes. No tengo claro cómo se puede modificar la estructura del JSON, aunque **seguro** que se puede

Comment: ¿Usas Spring? Si es así creo que con añadir un manejador de excepciones en tus controladores valdría: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135588/how-to-change-response-json-returned-corresponding-to-notnull-annotation